# Histogram slider in Javascript

Tags: jquery-plugins, svg, javascript, d3.js

I am trying to build a slider filter, which enables users to select a numerical range of a filter. I want to add a histogram image(i.e. svg) as a background of the slider. Currently I am considering d3.js or jQuery Sparkline, and a jQuery slider or HTML5 native slider element. Can someone give any suggestions on Javascript library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compare:

- **`<input type="range">`:** [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/Input#Attributes), does not require an extra library.
- **jQuery slider:** [Cross-browser](http://jqueryui.com/slider/), can have much control over the appearance.
- **Sparkline:** [a jQuery plugin](http://omnipotent.net/jquery.sparkline/), even *more* control (never use it, can't tell)

The most important thing is, depending how you are using it, choose the one that best fit your purpose. Sometimes a simple jQuery slider is enough, but in some case a plugin might do even more.